# '1004': That sort reference is not valid. Make sure that it's within the data you want to sort, and the first Sort By box isn't the same or blank

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sort a range for one value to display in order from smallest to largest, but for some reason am getting the above error at ".Apply". Does anyone know how to fix this? this is for something due soon, so prompt help would be a real lifesaver!

```
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Filter ClientID").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Filter ClientID").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
    Key:=Range("O9:O50"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Filter ClientID").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: You can't "sort a range for one value". You might filter a range for one value. If the range was previously sorted the portion displayed by the filter will be sorted, too. Accordingly, first sort your data and then filter them.

Comment: If the sheet you're sorting isn't active then the Key will be on a different sheet.

Comment: The problem is first I run an advanced filter to narrow down the results, and then I have to run another filter on the results to organize them smallest to largest, so I cannot filter by price beforehand.